# Account Creation Form not showing In Contribution Page

Tags: profile, user-account

I created a profile and enabled account creation required. I attached the profile at the Contribution Page, but the account sign-up form is now showing up when I am not logged in.
I am using Wordpress 4.4.2 with CiviCRM 4.6.8.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ditto about doing this on demo site and providing links if you are able to replicate. it really helps if we know the problem is generic (ie replicable on demo) versus something unique to your site/system/setup

Comment: Thanks but i have resolved this. The problem was that i did not set that anyone can register in wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks but i have resolved this. The problem was that i did not set that anyone can register in wordpress –

Comment: I am having thesame problem again. But the above solution is not working. I have deactivated all plugins individually still the username and password fields is not showing. i have changed template still thesame problem. Does anyone have any idea?